How to calculate week over week %share in Power BI?
Attached is a sample data showing customer name , week number and $Amt. I have created a pivot to show %of weekly total.
How to show WoW % share in Power BI ?( expected result shown in column M and N)
Can you help to obtain the expected result ?
Sample Data /Pivot - enter image description here
Expected Result- enter image description here
I have created the percentage of weekly total in Power BI. I am stuck at figuring out the formula to obtain the WoW% share.
FYI, I am a newbie.Thanks in advance !

I would address this problem by creating a measure for each week number from 1 to 3. Then, you would create a measure to compare weeks to each other by dividing the previous measurements

You can try the following two measures:
% Share = 
  var x = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM(YourTable[$Amt])
    )
  var y = 
    CALCULATE(
      SUM(YourTable[$Amt]),
      REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[Customer])
    )
  return
    DIVIDE( x, y )

% Share WoW = 
  var wk = MAX(YourTable[Week])
  var prevWk = 
    CALCULATE(
      [% Share],
      YourTable[Week] = wk - 1,
      REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[Week])
    )
  var thisWk = [% Share]
  return
    IF(
      ISBLANK(prevWk),
      BLANK(),
      thisWk - prevWk
    )


